# Grails: AJAX onSuccess method not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails, groovy

I am using the jquery library with the grails remoteFunction tag to make an AJAX call in the event of a mouseover. The from a println I wrote I know the designated action is being called, but the onSuccess function is never triggered. I checked firebug and I am receiving a 404 error. I am new to AJAX and JS in general, so I might be overlooking something very obvious right now. Here is my code snippet.

gsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function change()
{

document.getElementById('changer').src='${resource(dir: "images/images", file: "heart_red.png")}';
}

function onSuccess(data){

    alert("Has hearted:");

}
```

```
<img class="user_profile_pic" src="${user.profilePicture}" onmouseover="${remoteFunction(controller:'user', action: 'hasHearted', onSuccess: 'onSuccess(data)', params:[userID: user.id])}"/>
```

groovy:

```
    def hasHearted = {
    println "Recieved user ID: $params.userID" 
    if(some condition...){
        [hasHearted: true] as JSON
    }
    else{
        [hasHearted: false] as JSON
    }

}
```

Comment: First thing I would do is use something like Firebug to make sure your hasHearted action is returning correctly.  If onSuccess isn't called, it could be that it isn't successful, even though it made it to the server.  You have to verify the round trip.  Not just one way.

Comment: You should really seperate the scripts from the HTML..

Comment: Thanks, firebug was a great idea. I am receiving a 404 error. Any ideas of what can be going on?

Comment: 404? First thing to look, is your controller name and action name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use *render* method in the controller:

```
render ([hasHearted: true] as JSON)
```

Comment: Otherwise Grails "assumes" that you still want to render view (GSP), that is default behavior